# How to work out the complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory, analysis

I have two questions for algorithm analysis, and would like to know how to determine the complexity of the following two:

First:

```
For(int i=2; i<n; i=i*i*i)
{
  //something O(1)
}
```

Second:

```
n/1 + n/2 + n/3 +...+ n/n
```

Comment: you should answer your exam questions by yourself

Answer (score 1):

To the first:

It will be infinite, because `1*1*1 = 1` so i is always 1 and will never be `>= n`.

The second algorithm is not really an algorithm but the addition runs in `O(n)`.

Comment: What would be the complexity of the first if `i` starts at 2?

Comment: How if int i not start at 1? let say i start at 2?

Comment: I'm not completly sure but I think `n^(1/3)` please correct someone if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For the first Algorithm:

Suppose that the initial value of `i` is 2 (rather than 1 that would lead to an infinite loop as @tschaefemedia remarked).

At the 1st iteration, i==2

At the second iteration, i==2*2*2 == 2ˆ3

At the third iteration, i== (2ˆ3 * 2ˆ3 * 2ˆ3) == 2ˆ(3*3)

At the fourth iteration, i== 2ˆ(3*3) * 2ˆ(3*3) * 2ˆ(3*3) == 2ˆ(3*3*3)

...

At iteration k+1, i== 2ˆ(3*3*3*...*3) == 2ˆ(3ˆk)

Suppose for simplicity that at iteration k-1, i becomes equal to n and the loop stops. Then:

n == 2ˆ(3ˆk)

log2(n) == 3^k

log3(log2(n)) == k

So, the complexity is O(log3(log2(n)))

As for the second question, I suppose that you are giving the complexity formula. So,

n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n = n (1+ 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n)

This is Harmonic series and it is O(log(n))

So, the overall complexity is O(n*log(n))

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer.. It's very helpful..
Can you please help me one more time to explain
        for(int i=0,j=1;i<n;i+=j,j++)
 {} Thanks

Comment: Try to proceed as I did in the first question. You will find that, at iteration k+1, the value of i is 1+2+3+ ... + k, which is k*(k+1)/2. If we stop at this iteration, then n == k*(k+1)/2 which is approximately kˆ2. So, k==sqrt(n). The complexity is O(sqrt(n))